# Is the potential operator always a multiplication operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential-energy

I am talking in the context of quantum mechanics. Is there a case where $\hat{V}$ does not simply multiply the function it operates on with itself, $V(x,t)$?

For the harmonic oscillator: $\hat{V}\psi = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi$. It just multiplies the wavefunction. Is there any case where $\hat{V} = \partial_x$, for example? Does it even make any physical sense to have a potential energy function depend on the wavefunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for in terms of momentum-dependent potentials but a function of $x$ such as $V(x)$ acts by multiplication on $\psi(x)$ in position space but it will act by derivative $\hat x\to -i\hbar \partial_p$ on the momentum wavefunctions $\psi(p)$.  On such functions it is the momentum that acts by multiplication: $\hat p\psi(p)=p\psi(p)$.

The usual example is the linear potential where
$$
\hat H=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+ \alpha \hat x
$$
with the Schrodinger equation
$$
\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}-i\alpha\hbar\frac{d}{dp}\right)\psi(p)=E\psi(p)
$$
in momentum space.

The solution in position space is an Airy function.  In momentum space integration is immediate.

Comment: I didn't realize that a potential operator that includes partial derivative with respect to position implied momentum dependence. This makes very much sense!

Comment: I suppose partial derivative with respect to time would imply $V(E)$ because $\hat{E} = i\hbar \partial_t$? Of course, I don't think this makes sense physically but at least mathematically?

Comment: I've never see the above $V(E)$.  Since $V$ is a potential how can it itself depend on $E$?  $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(p)$ are related via (spatial) Fourier transform and this is what induces $x\to -i\hbar \partial_p$.

Comment: Yes, I was just editing my comment to point that out. But mathematically at least? Anyways, I just didn't see the connection originally which comes from using different bases. I think I understand now!